# How to serve a static folder in sails.js?

Tags: sails.js

I want to serve a folder `app`, which is at the same level with `assets` folder, under the url `/app`.

It's possible with `AppController` to serve file according the url, but I want to know whether it is possible to do this like the following with express?

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: Please look at this StackOverflow QA: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41164733/1056679.

Comment: The fact that there is not default behavior included in sails.js really scares me on the framework itself...

Answer (score 12):

You can use custom middleware for express in sails by adding it to your config/http.js:

```
var express = require('express');
module.exports.express = {
  customMiddleware: function (app) {
      app.use(express.logger());
      app.use(express.compress());
      app.use('/app', express.static(process.cwd() + '/../client/www/'));
    }
};
```

Comment: answer is good, but second line is missing "var app = express();"

Comment: customMiddleware is deprecated in sails v1.0

Comment: check my answer for sails v.1.0

Answer (score 6):

Off the top of my head, there's two choices:

1. Create a symlink `assets/app` pointing to your destination. The resources should be accessible via `http://your.host.com/app/*` since that's the way Sails serves assets.
2. There's still Express underneath Sails, you should be able to access it with `sails.express.app` and do your thing, let's say, from `config/bootstrap.js`:

   `var express = require('express');`

   …

   `sails.express.app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/app'));`

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have index.html which is SPA (backbone and require.js)... how can I serve that within sails.js?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097679/confusion-about-web-application-ports/21099224#21099224

Comment: I tried creating a new directory inside assets, but sails is not serving files that are in the new directory.

Comment: Nevermind. I didn't put an extension on the end of my filename so apparently the url was interpreted as a directory instead of a file and then failed because this nonexistent directory didn't have an `index.html` file in it.

Comment: looks like sails.express.app does not exist

Comment: @eyn yeah, this was for before v1, and it's been a while, so you should probably look at the docs for the version you're using

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Sails.js v0.12.4.  The http.js uses `module.exports.http` and not `module.exports.express`  I did the following to serve up another folder like the existing `/assets` folder. In my example to serve up the `app` folder, replace the `'node_modules/bootstrap/dist'` path with `/app`

In the `config/http.js` file I added

```
var express = require('express');
```

Then in the `middleware` object I added the express static module. I'm wanting to serve up the bootstrap assets contained in my `node_modules` folder.

```
bootstrapAssets: express.static('node_modules/bootstrap/dist'),
```

Then in the `order` array, I added the `'bootstrapAssets'` in the order I wanted this middleware to run.  Here is the full code:

```
var express = require('express');

module.exports.http = {

  middleware: {

    passportInit    : require('passport').initialize(),
    passportSession : require('passport').session(),

    bootstrapAssets : express.static('node_modules/bootstrap/dist'),


    order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'bootstrapAssets',
      'passportInit',
      'passportSession',
      'myRequestLogger',
      'bodyParser',
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ],
```

Now in my HTML I can access the the bootstrap css using the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 4):

In **Sails 1.0** you can modify the file *config/routes.js* and add this:

```
var express = require('express')
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')
var os = require('os')

const dir = `${os.homedir()}/foo` // dir = /home/dimas/foo

module.exports.routes = {

  '/public/*': serveStatic(dir, {skipAssets: true}), // <-- ADD THIS

  '/': {
    controller: 'FooController',
    action: 'checkLogin'
  },

};
```

Then you have to create the directory structure:

```
/home/dimas/foo/public
```

**NOTE** that the *public* entry (the route) is INCLUDED in the *filesystem path*, the files to be served must be placed there!

After that you can access any content by hitting the following URL:

http://localhost:1337/public/foratemer.txt

Comment: `dir` can be a relative path, so you can just do `serveStatic('foo', {skipAssets: true})`

Answer (score 1):

You can serve your files simple like this:

```
var express = require('../node_modules/sails/node_modules/express');

module.exports.express = {
  middleware: {
    custom: true
  },

  customMiddleware: function (app) {
    app.use(express.logger());
    app.use(express.compress());
    app.use('/api/docs',express.static('assets/swagger-ui/dist/'));
  }
};
```

This is my config/express.js file

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for sails 0.12.3:

- Install express to your sail: npm install express --save
- After that, modify config/route.js

  `module.exports.routes = {
  ...
  '/public/*': require('express').static('the-directory-that-contains-public-director')
  ...
  }`

This will works. However, it is a bit ugly that you have to create a directory as a parent for your public directory. It is because the static middleware create by express will count the '/public/' prefix in calculating to path to the target files.

Comment: you saved my life by telling about **the prefix**... now it is working again!

Answer (score 0):

Sails v1.0: Serve a file with a . dot folder in sails. Example: https://myWebSite.com/.well-known/test.txt

in the config/http.js file add express.static to serve and then add publicFolder in the order array.

```js
module.exports.http = {
middleware: {

publicFolder: express.static('public/public'),

  order: [
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'publicFolder'
      // 'favicon',
    ],
}}
```

Create a public folder and .well-known folder so public/.well-known/test.txt