# Confusion about web-application ports

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, sails.js

I have a project that is already deep in development, and there is a problem with the ports.

The Client is SPA written in backbone, that uses Sails as a server.

Problem is in the fact that Client is running in Express on port 80, while Sails is run on 1337.

I would like to host this backbone application within the Sails, not ouside the sails.
A bit more details: 
When I fire the Fiddler, I am seeing requests being made to localhost:1337/get/user.
I need it to reside on port 80 as well.

Backbone is written using standard. I have app.js and main.js with all of the common folders (JS, LIBS, CSS). In other words, I have index.html that has data-main using require.js...

I have not problems running the client in separate node.js... how to run it within Sails.js?

Where do I put my index.html???

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-an-node-js-app-using-sails-js-on-an-ubuntu-vps << scroll down to setting server to production mode

Comment: I have seen that link. I have index.html that in turn has data-main which calls require and Backbone magic is fired there... After lots of reading, it seems that I can out that stuff under assets folder in sails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to serve `index.html` as a static file won't work. Instead, try the following:

**1. Serve your `index.html` from Sails**

Just serve `index.html` as a combination of `views/layout.ejs` and `views/home/index.ejs`, which are mounted to the root `/` for default newly created Sails project.

**2. Set up a catch-all route**

In `config/routes.js` put something like this:

```
module.exports.routes = {
  '/': {
    view: 'home/index'
  },

  '/:unknownRoute': {
    view: 'home/index'
  }
}
```

This way you'll be able, for example, to use simple one-level pushstate routing within your SPA: routes like `/products` or `/news` will still give you your `index.html` (if you are using something more complex though, you may want to play a little bit more with your Sails routes).

**3. Serve your API with a prefix**

In your `config/controllers.js` put, for example:

```
module.exports.controllers = {
  ...

  prefix: '/api',

  ...
}
```

This will let you serve your API with a prefix and have both `/api/products` (JSON API) and `/products` (your SPA) routes available.

**4. Use any port you want**

You can change the default port via `config/local.js`, even to `80` (if you don't have anything else running on `80`, of course).

In production though, it would probably be a better idea to just proxy to default Sails' or any other port with Nginx, for example.

Comment: So it means, I can serve my index.html right there and it should work? I will give it a try first thing next morning. I will post the results here.

Comment: If you really want to serve it through Sails application, yes, it will work. Another (somewhat cleaner) way could be, for example, serving `index.html` and assets as static files with Apache or Nginx on `http://www.whatever.com/` and Sails API on `http://api.whatever.com/`. They both have pros and cons though.

Comment: Currently I am serving Backbone on separate Express using port 80, and sails is serving on default port 1337... is there something wrong with it?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it, it's just that probably you don't need Node / Express at all to serve static files, that's the idea. But the question was about serving everything from one process (Sails), so that's the way to do it. This approach is easier for development. The separation-based approach is more flexible, especially in terms of scalability. But you can always separate your client app from the API later, as long as you are not slopping it out of the `assets` folder (that's where your Backbone files go) too much.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I will give it a try first thing tomorrow and post results.