# Should I install angular2 or @angular node_modules?

Tags: angular, sails.js

Regarding installing dependencies for angular2 using with my sails.js web app.  Should I install angular2 (current v2.0.0-beta.17) or @angular ( current v2.0.0-rc.3) node_modules? I am confused as to which node modules I am suppose to use.

If I am suppose to use @angular node_modules, can some one write the steps needed for @Angular node_modules to work with sails.js app.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version you want to use. There was a package renaming between beta and RC versions. You can use only one at a time: either angular2 or @angular...

Comment: refer this link may be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35131611/integrating-sails-js-with-angular-2