# How do I serve static files using Sails.js only in development environment?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, assets, middleware

On production servers, we use `nginx` to serve static files for our Sails.js application, however in development environment we want Sails to serve static files for us. This will allow us to skip nginx installation and configuration on dev's machines.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to show you how you could solve this using [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static) module for Node.js/Express.

1). First of all install the module for development environment: `npm i -D serve-static`.

2). Create `serve-static` directory inside of `api/hooks` directory.

3). Create the `index.js` file in the `serve-static` directory, created earlier.

4). Add the following content to it:

```
module.exports = function serveStatic (sails) {

  let serveStaticHandler;

  if ('production' !== sails.config.environment) {
    // Only initializing the module in non-production environment.
    const serveStatic = require('serve-static');
    var staticFilePath = sails.config.appPath + '/.tmp/public';
    serveStaticHandler = serveStatic(staticFilePath);
    sails.log.info('Serving static files from: «%s»', staticFilePath);
  }

  // Adding middleware, make sure to enable it in your config.
  sails.config.http.middleware.serveStatic = function (req, res, next) {
    if (serveStaticHandler) {
      serveStaticHandler.apply(serveStaticHandler, arguments);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  };


  return {};

};
```

5). Edit `config/http.js` file and add the previously defined middleware:

```
module.exports.http = {
  middleware: {
    order: [
      'serveStatic',
      // ...
    ]
  }
};
```

6). Restart/run your application, e.g. `node ./app.js` and try to fetch one of static files. It should work.