# send file from sails.js web server to android app

Tags: android, node.js, sails.js

I have an Android app
I also have a web server that has been programmed with Sails.js.
The Android app communicates with this web server.
For example, the Android app sends a request to the server that the server sends back 20 images for the Android app as a response.

Now, my question is, how should I send these images to the Android app?(In Sails.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

*Option 1:*

The first request return array of urls, url for each image, and the Android app should use each url to display the image.

For example it can be json response:

```
{images: [{url: "http://example.com/image1.jpg"}, {url: "http://example.com/image2.jpg"}]}
```

If the images are static files, you can see here
[How to serve a static folder in sails.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543252/how-to-serve-a-static-folder-in-sails-js#21654815)

*Option 2:*

The server can return array of the images themself, each item in the array can be the base64 encoded image data.

So the steps are:

1. Get the base64 encoded images, if you want to take them from file you can see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523532/ddg#24526156
2. Put the images into array and send it as the http response

   ```
   {images:[{data: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg...."},{data: "data:image/png;base64,/9j/1414...."}]}
   ```
3. Display the base64 encoded file in the Android app.
   I dont have any experience in Android development, but maybe this answer will help you:
   [How to convert a Base64 string into a BitMap image to show it in a ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837110/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-bitmap-image-to-show-it-in-a-imageview#4837293)

Comment: I'm currently using Option 1 and I will send the name of all the images as an Json object.
Please, if it is possible for you, to more explain Option 2 with one example.

Comment: I edited it.
Do you have a good reason why to use option 2? I dont see any reason in most cases...

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was very useful